# Count consecutive rows in mySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm trying to figure out counting the consecutive values row after row.
I have a mySQL / php website.

Based on Racing league results table, I have such example data:

(race id, season number, track number, first (p1), second (p2).... last (p2) filled with pilot ID).

```
id, season, track, p1,  p2....  p20
1,  1,      1,      1,  4, .... 15
2,  1,      2,      3,  5, .... 15
3,  1,      3,      1,  4, .... 15
4,  1,      4,      1,  2, .... 15
5,  1,      5,      1,  4, .... 15
6,  1,      6,      2,  2, .... 15
7,  1,      7,      2,  4, .... 15
8,  1,      8,      1,  2, .... 15
```

As you can see, pilotID n.1 won 3 times consecutively, from race 3 to race 5, while pilotID n.2 won 2 times consecutively, from race 6 to race 7.

My goal output table would be:

```
count,  pilot,  fromRaceID,     toRaceID
3,      1,      3,              5
2,      2,      6,              7
```

ordered by count.

I know it is complicated, and even mightn't be possible; I found major difficulties trying to do so, therefore your help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: What is you mysql version.

Comment: My mySQL version is 5.6

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands.  Subtract a sequence number and the "adjacent" values will be constant:

```
select p1, min(trackid), max(trackid), count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by p1 order by track_number) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by p1, (track_number - seqnum)
having count(*) > 1;
```

EDIT:

In older versions of MySQL, you can use:

```
select p1, min(trackid), max(trackid), count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from t t2
              where t2.p1 = t.p1 and t2.track_number <= t.track_number
             ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by p1, (track_number - seqnum)
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your greatful help. Anyway, I got a Syntax error, mySQL says near "Partition by".

Comment: Gordon, Dont you think OP needs all P1-P20 in the output not only P1. I guess You have to give a second thought to your answer.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . As I understand the question, the OP only cares about winners which are in `p1`.